# delete specific rows from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete specific rows from one data frame

the data frame has `176039`rows and I want to delete the `2%` of them at the beginning and `2%` at the end of the data frame

the dataframe is as follow

```
    activity    accx    accy    accz    gyrx    gyry    gyrz
  0 downstairs  0.660583    0.454468    -0.585022   32.366615   27.206556    
  -23.471800
  1 downstairs  0.668640    0.454102    -0.577698   32.442837   27.168446    
 -24.679878
  2 downstairs  0.672241    0.453613    -0.574158   33.647106   26.280489    
 -25.243902
  3 downstairs  0.688599    0.454041    -0.574768   34.676067   25.076220    
 -26.204270
  4 downstairs  0.692017    0.443604    -0.559814   34.855183   25.003810    
 -27.317074
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `iloc` and get indexes that are (to the nearest entry) `2%` and `98%` along the way.

```
num = len(df)
df = df.iloc[int(0.02 * num):int(0.98 * num)]
```

---

Per your amendum, you can make sure your dataframe has a multiple of 200 rows by:

```
df = df.iloc[:-(len(df) % 200)]
```

Comment: thanks that work. one more question, please. with your code, I end up with 166998 rows. I am using windows as the data is time series. so in order to see the total number of windows, I do 166998/200 and this gives me 844.99 windows. how to remove these lines from the dataset in order to have exactly 844 windows?

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to say. Do you just want to make sure the number of rows is a multiple of 200?